# How can I cross reference search a database?

Tags: mysql, join

I have a table with the following columns

```
 id       | id of row 
 name     | id referencing visitor_table
 reason   | array of ids referencing reason table
 comment  | comment value
 indate   | indate value
 contact  | id referencing contacts table
```

When a user types in text I need to execute a query that joins all of these tables by their IDs so that the data in the referenced tables can be queried also. Is it reasonable to join this many tables or how might I make something more efficient?

Answer (score 0):

In case you have the luxury of modifying table schema you could go for [Big table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BigTable) type design.

Answer (score 0):

The overhead due to joins is countered, to an extent, by indexing the tables.